# Shadow/Elevation from Collapse Tool Bar Don'tWork With Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

I'm studying the Udacity Material Design for Android Course.

In the classes "Making Scrollable Dinamic Surface" I learn how make a action bar that change size with scrolling.

But this example works with a ScrollView for the content.
When I try to use a RecyclerView I lost the Shadow effect between action bar and content.

Should I set something different?
Thanks.

XML Code with ScrollView and Recycler View(commented):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/glasses_dogs" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
<!--android:id="@+id/main_home_list"-->
<!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"-->
<!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />-->

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:text="@string/cupcake_ipsum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
</ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

Comment: Do your component have a background color? I think `elevation` work if the component has a background color.

Comment: @WilliamBertan They had, even is a adapter with two layouts (title + content). And if I remember well what should have background is what is elevated, actionbar in case

Comment: Can you add your layout xml to the question?

Comment: @WilliamBertan I just Add. Thanks for the help. If you need in this question (not answered :'( ) I have the codes of my layouts adapters for the recycler view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732585/layout-behavior-with-an-adapter-inside-another-one

Comment: Where is your `elevation` tag?

Comment: @WilliamBertan There is not, was something already default from this collapse Toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

In your XML you can add a Animator (last line)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="@color/neah_screen_bg_white"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated">
```

You create this XML file in res/animator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="elevation"
        android:valueTo="4dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:duration="1"/>
</item>
</selector>
```